# Threading using Python in Raspberry Pi for GPIO inputs

Tags: gpio, python, robotics

My self-working on encoders of differential drive robot, I need to read the speed and position of wheels using two encoders simultaneously. I have used the threading library in Python even though I started both functions. Only the function initiated first runs while the second doesn't. I am not sure what the cause of this is. Is there anything to be noted while using threading in GPIO pins of Raspberry Pi 3 B? If so, please help and suggest a solution.

```
from threading import Thread
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime 

def encoder_right(t1):
    
    ...
        
def encoder_left(t1):
    
    ...

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

Thread1 = Thread(target = encoder_right(t1),daemon = True)

Thread2 = Thread(target = encoder_left(t1),daemon = True)

Thread1.start()

Thread2.start()

Thread1.join()

Thread1.join()
```

Comment: Asking a programming question without code is futile. Threading in Python is complex; due to GIL only 1 thread can run python code at a time.

Comment: i have added the code please provide a solution

Comment: It is difficult to understand this code. Do your initialisation ONCE outside your functions. Your functions NEVER exit so join will never do anything. It is unclear WHY you are using threads - surely a callback would be simpler.

Comment: I have to read the data from encoder lively   while my code has to perform other operation,so i used threading here.

Comment: This is off-topic as it is a general programming question.

Answer (score 0):

In both lines you initialize thread object you make a mistake passing whatever your functions return instead of the function itself. So simply replace both lines with:

```
Thread1 = Thread(target=encoder_right, args=[t1], daemon=True)
Thread2 = Thread(target=encoder_left, args=[t1], daemon=True)
```